# create XML nodes based on XPath in java

Tags: java, dom, xpath

I have a configuration file may or may not contain a certain element whose XPath is:

```
/configuration/server/address
```

when I write the configuration I have to create the node if it doesn't exist.

```
Node n = (Node)xp.evaluate("/configuration/server/address", configDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

but, no surprise, node is null if the node doesn't exist in the real file.

**QUESTION**

Ok. My idea is have something like File: i can define a path that doesn't exist:

```
File f = new File("myInexistentDir/myInexistentSubdir");
```

then, i call *f.mkdirs()* and the path is replicated in the real world.
Is it possible with java implementation of XPath?

Possible objection. It's obvious that not all XPath expressions are "creatable nodes".
Where create the "//anywhere" element? 
I would say that "//anywhere" expression doesn't is a "path" in a strict sense, it's more similar to a query.

Comment: Another difference is that an XML file can have multiple nodes with the same name at the same level.  This is not possible in the file system.  Thus a path to a file always refers to exactly one specific thing.  An xpath can refer to multiple nodes at multiple levels all across the XML document.

Comment: While possible, an generic solution will be kind of extensive - what do you need this stuff for anyways?

Comment: I have never seen such a thing, but I will implement it in [jOOX](http://code.google.com/p/joox/issues/detail?id=82), very nice idea!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like this exists that I've ever seen. A quick glance at the JavaDocs of some of the alternative parsers didn't find anything either. [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/apidocs/) returns a `Nodes` object from it's XPath engine, which does allow inserts. That might get you close to what you need.